# Problems comparing a string to an array of strings C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am about to have a stroke, I cannot figure why this code doesn't work. The goal is to search an array of strings for a string. If the string being searched for is found, the method returns true, and if not, false. Unfortunately I've made some sort of error, and am about to have a stroke, because I cannot figure out what it is. The printf is just there to show that the array is being iterated through, your help is much appreciated. Also, the -1 in the for loop is just something that helps, I don't think it should be there, but watch what happens when you take it out. Also, I'd like to point out that that the way I declared the array is the way I need to, because of the section I am currently studying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool seachForString(char *firstString, int numberOfStrings, char *searchingFor);

int main(void){

  bool found;
  char *search = "Earth";

  char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
  found = seachForString(planets[0], 9, search);

  printf("Found: %d\n", found);

  return 0;
}

bool seachForString(char *firstString, int numberOfStrings, char *searchingFor){
  char *stringInList = firstString;

  for(int i=0; i<numberOfStrings-1; i++){
    printf("%s\n", stringInList);
    if(strcmp(stringInList, searchingFor) == 0){
      return true;

    }else{
      while(*(stringInList++) != '\0');

    }

  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the else? I think removing it will make this work

Comment: need it to iterate through the array, if the string stringInList  points to isn't the string I am looking for, then the pointer needs to be incremented until it is at the first char in the next string

Comment: @holycatcrusher: The strings are not guaranteed to be allocated sequentially.

Comment: is `seachForString` a mandated function signature? I'd rather just pass in the whole `planets[]` array, then you could loop through that with an index, `strcmp`ing until you find your planet. No need for `stringInList`

Comment: [try this](http://ideone.com/MilywK)

Comment: Code works if strings are allocated sequentially.  What is your error or unexpected output?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's a perfect solution, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as right.

Comment: @lolololol ol the problem is it doesn't return the correct value when a string in the list is passed

Comment: @Dani, That is likely the problem I guess. I will have to look into that now. Based on the symptoms that would be a possible cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `char *search = "Earth";`  after `char *planets[] = {...};`, it may work.
E.g.

```
char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
char *search = "Earth";
```

However, placement of string literals is not always what you want. There is no such guarantee.

So change it to pass the array.

like this:

```
bool seachForString(char *firstString[], int numberOfStrings, char *searchingFor);

int main(void){

  bool found;
  char *search = "Earth";

  char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
  found = seachForString(planets, 9, search);

  printf("Found: %d\n", found);

  return 0;
}

bool seachForString(char *firstString[], int numberOfStrings, char *searchingFor){
  char **stringInList = firstString;

  for(int i=0; i<numberOfStrings; i++){
    printf("%s\n", *stringInList);
    if(strcmp(*stringInList++, searchingFor) == 0)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```